# How to secure Jquery and asp.net page method call

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i call my asp.net page method like below code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyPage.aspx/GetItems",
        data: "{'ID':'1', 'Name':'Keith'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
           // my success code
        }
    });
```

the above way i call my asp.net pagemethod using jquery. so if anyone see the page source then he can see what page i am calling and what values i am passing. so anyone can call my page same way and get the data.

so here i need to incorporate some tokenid which i will generate at runtime and will pass to server side function. in this case again user can see the tokenid but if he copy my tokenid then that tokenid will not work for him. so i just need logic to generate dynamic tokenid which will be valid only form my web apps.

please share the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this way:

1. server side: create session variable that store Dictonary<'tokenid', 'context'>
2. client side: use only tokenid

TokenId be generated via Guid.NewGuid or RNGCryptoServiceProvider.
Context - is some data associating with token (in your case it's 'ID').

Thereby

- we never send real ids to client side
- tokenid is randomness and unrepeatable
- user cannot get access to general data

Comment: can u please show me a sample code the way u manage security with ('tokenid', 'context') u said. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can use ajax on their websites to access your data, if you mean that.
Cross-domain policy doesn't allow browsers to access other websites through ajax.
Is this enough, or you have a completely different problem?

Comment: so u mean to say i can not call aspx page method of another site from my site if i know the exact page url. suppose like  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "www.othersite.com/Others_Page.aspx/GetItems",
            data: "{'pageIndex':'" + page + "', 'pageSize':'" + per_page + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, first, last, data.d, page);
            }
        }); please guide me. thanks

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's a carousel or an airplane. Modern browsers will not allow you to make AJAX calls from your website to another.

Comment: @avetarman, that may be true for JSON, but check out JSONP.  It was designed specifically to make AJAX calls to a different domain. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: You can't use JSONP, if you don't have write access to server files. JSONP needs the processing {php,jsp,asp} to be modified in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting as I do not have a large enough reputation to make a comment. But the previous talking about the cross domain policy prevents someone from making an ajax call to access your data.
If you install a simple firefox add-on called firequery. You can add javascript/jquery calls from anywhere on the page and directly run them. (THE DOM AND ANYTHING CLIENT SIDE OF A PAGE CAN ALWAYS BE MANIPULATED BY THE BROWSER)

So for example I could have knowledge of a url and build up the jquery ajax call and place it directly into firequery and it will execute immediately all as an unauthenticated user but inside of the sites domain. I have exploited this problem in my companies products.

You cannot assume that cross domain policy will protect you.

Comment: You should really post in the comments if this is not answer, once you have sufficient rep to do so.